# ACM forbidden package

Tags: equations, packages, acm, optidef

I am preparing a latex document to submit to an ACM journal.
Unfortunately, they have only a [small list](https://www.acm.org/publications/taps/accepted-latex-packages) of allowed packages.

I use the package `optidef` to define optimization problems with constraints. But it is not included in the ACM list.

How can I overcome this?

Comment: Make pdf files, don't try to cheat, it will only annoy those receiving the article

Comment: May you show me a simple example?

Comment: Not at pc, so no. Make each image as a document of its own using the `standalone` class. At compilation of these you'll have standalone pdf files of each needed image which you then include in your article. Since latex in general generates vector grøfx, this is better than saving as png

Comment: Thank you, I used your solution (I had to lose consistency with fonts though). Nevertheless, I can't apply this solution to package `optidef`.

Comment: Regarding fonts, that should not be a problem to apply to those as well.

Comment: while you could do as suggested and include the definitions as PDF images I do not think that is a good plan here. The reason for the restriction stated at the publisher site is to ensure good translation to HTML. You will certainly not get that from an included PDF rendering of the equation. Just simply give up on optidef and set the problem with more basic amsmath constructs.

Answer (score 1):

I will recommend a route close to what @daleif suggests, but slightly different.

1. Produce images using TikZ `externalize` library and `acmart` document class, so your fonts are correct

```
\documentclass{acmart}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{external}
\tikzexternalize

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \draw [color=blue, fill=green](0,0) circle [radius=2];
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

2. Compile document using `pdflatex --shell-escape` (important!).  This saves each `tikzpicture` in a PDF file
3. Add these files to the main doc using `\includegraphics`